# Can angular filter an array by properties that don't exist?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to filter an array of objects by a property `scenarioVid`. If the property is false or undefined, I'd like to include it in the list. If the property is true, I'd like to exclude it.

I have this:

```
<li ng-repeat="script in content.activeContent.scripts | filter:{scenarioVid:false}
```

But in my array of objects, `scenarioVid` doesn't exist unless it is true. Otherwise it is not present in the object.

Nothing shows up in my list.

If I were to remove this filter, I'd get all `scripts`, which I don't want, because it's not filtered.

So when I try to filter by a property that doesn't exist, it doesn't evaluate to `false`? Does the property need to exist and be `false` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be accomplished with `ng-show`

```
<li ng-repeat="script in content.activeContent.scripts" ng-show="!script.scenarioVid"
```

Comment: or `ng-if` if you want to actually remove the element instead of just concealing it.

Comment: Wrong answer. The question was "how to FILTER list before iterating", not "how to hide unnesessary list items". What you will do with your soluttion, if you'll need a correct $index, for example?

Comment: You're right: `$index` will be different if we use angular's `filter`.
In simple scenarios - like the one here - `ng-show` / `ng-if` will accomplish the same thing.